# non existing record in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I worked with ArrayList quite often but now i have an error that the size of my ArrayList equals 623 items
[image]

But if i iterate over the list i'm missing some records in my list.
[image]

in the preview above i'm missing record 621, how can this be?
this list is final and immutable.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the IntelliJ debugger.

In the debugger, IntelliJ doesn't show null elements. Open up the expression evaluator, and grab the 621st element. I bet it will be null.

That element *has* to exist. The size is 623, and the indices go to 622, which is entirely expected. If that element were truly missing, the size would be off, and that would mean an ArrayList would be missing an element in the middle of it, which would be an exceedingly odd bug.

Comment: if i try to get element 622 it gives a null object back. but the problem is 623 items where going in and now is 1 items gone without an gc event. (yes it is IntelliJ Android Studio)

Comment: @quantumapps What do you mean "623 items where going in and now is 1 items gone without an gc event". No elements have disappeared. One of them is just null and not being shown in the debugger. Maybe one element went from a usable to null, but that's not the same as disappearing really. And you can't rely on the GC running at a certain time. It'll run when it runs. It's not like C++ where you can rely on the destructor running immediately. It's entirely up the JVM to decide when to run the GC. Also, are you sure the list is immutable?